# Oracle lookup function in loop returns rowtype how to get fields from rowtype

Tags: oracle, cursor, bulk, collect, rowtype

I have a procedure that runs a select ( I tested that is good returns 56 records )
then when I run a cursor I want to pass 3 fields to a function ( see above ) that will
lookup/select a record from a table that contains 15 million records ( 10 years worth ).

It returns a rowtype that I want to then extract the fields from this rowtype record to 
run an insert with both the records from the 1st select and the additional fields acquired
from the lookup function.

If I run the procedure the console prints out my test msgs but when I try to run

select * bulk collect into v_tab_proc_claim_recs from v_processed_claim;

it doesn't compile due to Error(97,65): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

as if either of these are not Tables.

Am I doing this right... how can I do it, why can't it see the table I'm trying to extract to ?

Should I do this some other way..

Thanks for any help/suggestions :)

The function is below....

```
create or replace function get_processed_claim_rec(

    p_provider VARCHAR2,
    p_rx VARCHAR2,
    p_record_no  NUMBER 
)


 return i_idb.processed_claim%rowtype
  as
    l_claim_record i_idb.processed_claim%rowtype;
  begin

    select * into l_claim_record from i_idb.processed_claim
      where source_date = p_provider
      AND rx = p_rx
      AND rec_no = p_record_no;


   return(l_claim_record);
  end;
```

And the procedure is....

```
create or replace PROCEDURE import_mailer_data

  AS
    -------------------------------

    /**
        for the lookup table
    **/
    v_processed_claim  i_idb.processed_claim%rowtype;
    TYPE proc_claim_recs IS TABLE OF v_processed_claim%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    v_tab_proc_claim_recs proc_claim_recs;
    --------------------------------

    CURSOR myCursor
    IS
    SELECT * 
      from
      (   
      SELECT
        j.create_date as open_date,
        case when (j.create_date < (sysdate - 20) )
            then 'POD'
            else 'REG'
        end as priority,
        c.division,
        c.unit,
        --p.refill as days_supply,
        --p.din_name,
       'CM_JOHN' as log_code,
        c.first_name,
        c.last_name,
        --p.UNLISTED_compound,
        --p.intervention_code,
        --p.substitution,
        --p.confirm,
        c.PROVIDER,
        c.rx,
        c.DISPENSE_DATE,
        c.DIN,
        c.QTY,
        c.DIN_COST_PAID,
        c.DISP_FEE_PAID,
        c.PAID_AMOUNT,
        c.SOURCE_DATE,
        c.RECORD_NO,
        c.RELATIONSHIP,
        c.INSURER_NO,
        c.GROUP_NO,
        c.CERTIFICATE,
        c.BIRTH_DATE,
        c.USER_ID,
        --p.rej_code --v_seq_no
          rank() over
          (
            partition by c.provider, c.rx, c.record_no Order by c.provider desc, c.rx desc

          ) as RNK         
      FROM AUDITCOLLECTIONS.MAILER_CLAIMS c,
        AUDITCOLLECTIONS.MAILER_JOBS j
      WHERE MAILER_JOB_DETAIL_ID IN
        (SELECT MAILER_JOB_DETAIL_ID
        FROM AUDITCOLLECTIONS.MAILER_JOB_DETAILS
        WHERE MAILER_JOB_ID IN
          ( SELECT MAILER_JOB_ID FROM AUDITCOLLECTIONS.MAILER_JOBS
          )
        )

        AND ( c.PROVIDER, c.rx, c.record_no ) NOT IN
          ( SELECT provider, rx, rec_no FROM  AUDITCOLLECTIONS.COLLECTION_AUDIT_STAGING
          )
        AND j.create_date > (sysdate - 30)
        AND c.provider = '2010500042'
      ) A_Latest
      where A_Latest.RNK = 1;

    BEGIN
    v_report_id := audit_load.create_loaded_report(v_report_type_id);

      FOR curRec IN myCursor
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          dbms_output.put_line ('===>>>> PRINTING TEST1 = ');        

        v_processed_claim := get_processed_claim_rec(curRec.PROVIDER, curRec.RX, curRec.RECORD_NO);


        select * bulk collect into v_tab_proc_claim_recs from v_processed_claim; 



      END LOOP;

      audit_load.update_status_to_loaded(v_report_id);
    END import_mailer_data;
```

Comment: "as if either of these are not Tables" - `v_processed_claim` is a variable of type `%rowtype` - it is **not** a table!

Comment: yes Tony and I'm trying to get the record out of that into a table so I can use/select it in my loop with the cursor....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 FOR curRec IN myCursor
  LOOP

      v_processed_claim := 
         get_processed_claim_rec(curRec.PROVIDER, curRec.RX, curRec.RECORD_NO);

      v_tab_proc_claim_recs (v_tab_proc_claim_recs.COUNT+1) := v_processed_claim;

  END LOOP;
```

Or simplify to:

```
 FOR curRec IN myCursor
  LOOP

      v_tab_proc_claim_recs (v_tab_proc_claim_recs.COUNT+1) :=
        get_processed_claim_rec(curRec.PROVIDER, curRec.RX, curRec.RECORD_NO);

  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks that much compiles !     Then in the context of the procedure above how do I then get the fields out of the v_tab_proc_claim_recs table ... do another select and cursor on this one record table ?

Comment: You can't **select** from that index-by array, you can just loop though it a record at a time.